# odoo launching wizard attributes

Tags: odoo

While launching a wizard, we use some attributes in the `act_window`, such as:

```
view_mode="form"
target="new"
key2="client_action_multi"
```

So, what is the meaning of `target="new"` and `key2="client_action_multi` and what would happen if we remove them?

Answer (score 0):

From Odoo 11 Wizard Documentation:

Wizards are launched by ir.actions.act_window records, with the field target set to the value new. The latter opens the wizard view into a popup window.

`target = new` opens the wizard in a new window.

Visit [Odoo 11 Wizard](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html#wizards) to learn more about the wizards.

Comment: I removed target=new from the code, but the wizard is still opened in a new window!